# PHP - Trim string containing <a href=

Tags: php

I need a way of taking a string that contains `<a href="url">something</a>` and remove it completely from the string.

So,

```
$text = 'Something string <a href="url">something</a> some more string';
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Should be easy but in the example you gave, what would you want to remove?

Comment: please be more specific with your question what's your aim ..

Comment: @CLiown If you want to remove a tag from your string than very simpler way in php use strip_tags($text)  that can remove all html tags from your string.

Comment: @CLiown  If you want some tags in string for that you have to provide that tag in second parameter like 
// Allow <p> and <a>
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a>');

Answer (score 3):

[`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php):

Removing an anchor is as simple as using this function

```
echo strip_tags($text)
```

In case you would want to allow the tag, just add it as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

[`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$text = str_replace('<a href="url">something</a>', '', $text);
```

And, if there's a little more variables, [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$text = preg_replace('/<a href="[^"]+">.+?</a>/i', '', $text);
```

However, there are several risks and shortcomings when combining HTML and regex.

Comment: i dont think he meant literally `<a href="url">something</a>` lol

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone No, me neither. But in my experience people either (1) ask very specific questions or (2) ask very specific questions and expect generic answers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand you question perfectly, but you can use these PHP functions to replace the string:

[str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
str_replace();
```

or

[preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

```
preg_replace();
```